# refresh page on select option in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<div class="form-group" style="text-align: right;">
    <label for="city">Select No Rows Per Page</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="selectrows" style="width: 70px; text-align: right;">
        <option>25</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>100</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

`index.php`

I want to refresh index.php on select option.

Comment: You'll either need a form or JavaScript.

Comment: how i refresh using javascript

Comment: if you refresh the page, you will lose any previous selected options

Comment: I suspect "refresh" isn't what you are trying to do. Could you explain in more detail what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it this way, you somehow need to get the selected option to the "reloaded" page. You could do this as a GET parameter in the URL. So add this:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      location = 'index.php?selectrows=' + e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
    });
  });
</script>
```

In the PHP script you can then access the selected value using `$_GET['selectrows']`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function doReload(catid){
        document.location = 'samepage.php?catid=' + catid;

        /* But if you want to submit the form just comment above line and uncomment following lines*/
        //document.frm1.action = 'samepage.php';
        //document.frm1.method = 'post';
        //document.frm1.submit();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="frm1" id="frm1">
        <select name="catid" id="catid" onChange="doReload(this.value);">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---All Category---</option>
            <option value="1">Category One</option>
            <option value="2">Category Two</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Quit posting "try this" answers. And please learn how to format answers.